# Como mostrar apenas a div selecionada

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma lista com 3 elementos e 3 divs.

```
<ul>
    <li>Todos</li>
    <li>elemento 1</li>
    <li>elemento 2</li>
    <li>elemento 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="1">elemento 1</div>
<div id="2">elemento 2</div>
<div id="3">elemento 3</div>
```

O que e estou tentando fazer é clicar em um elemento da lista e mostrar a div correspondente e esconder as outras divs. Alguém pode me mostrar algumas maneiras de como fazer isso com jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se isso serve pra você:

```js
$(function() {
    $('ul#items li').click(function(){
        var item = $('.elem[data-item="' + $(this).attr('data-item') + '"]');
        if($(this).attr('data-item') == 'all') {
            $('div.elem').show();
            return;
        }
        item.show();                                     
        $('div.elem[data-item!="'+item.attr('data-item')+'"]').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
    <li data-item="1">elemento 1</li>
    <li data-item="2">elemento 2</li>
    <li data-item="3">elemento 3</li>
    <li data-item="all">Todos</li>
</ul>

<div data-item="1" class="elem">elemento 1</div>
<div data-item="2" class="elem">elemento 2</div>
<div data-item="3" class="elem">elemento 3</div>
```

Os elementos são associados pelo atributo `data-item`, ou seja, a `li` onde o valor do atributo `data-item` é 3 vai mostrar a div com `data-item` 3 e esconder as outras.
O elemento com `data-item` igual a `all` vai mostrar todas as divs novamente.

Caso queira que as outras fiquem escondidas por padrão é só adicionar um `display: none` no css.

Comment: Obrigado André! Serviu sim. Eu modifiquei o código como faria pra mostrar todos os elementos?

Comment: @ewertonorg você diz mostrar todas as divs novamente? Tipo resetar o filtro?

Comment: Exato, quando clico na opção 'todos' e mostra todas as divs que tinha antes.

Comment: @ewertonorg editei minha resposta pra adicionar essa funcionalidade. Dá um olhada aí.

Comment: vlw André, +1 pra você! :D