# Alterar propriedade display com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Quero mudar o `display` das `div` conteudo_  para *block*, na medida em que for clicando e escondendo a que foi clicada anteriormente.

Como eu poderia fazer isso com o jQuery?

```css
.conteudo_1 {
  display: none
}

.conteudo_2 {
  display: none
}

.conteudo_3 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><a href="">Conteudo 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Conteudo 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Conteudo 3</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="conteudo_1">
  <p>
    texto conteudo 1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo_2">
  <p>
    texto conteudo 1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo_3">
  <p>
    texto conteudo 1
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer mudar o `display` ou esconder e mostrar o elemento ? Esconder e mostrar é só usar `show`/`hide` ou `toggle`.

Comment: quero mudar o display das div para block, na medida em que for clicando e escondendo a que foi clicada anteriormente

Comment: Veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46568/como-mostrar-apenas-a-div-selecionada) que o objetivo é bastante semelhante ao seu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo assim?

```js
function toggleDiv(conteudo){
  $('div.conteudo').removeClass('active');
  if(conteudo == 1){
    $('div.conteudo_1').addClass('active');
  }else if(conteudo == 2){
    $('div.conteudo_2').addClass('active');
  }else if(conteudo == 3){
    $('div.conteudo_3').addClass('active');
  } 
}
```

```css
.conteudo_1{
  display:none
}
.conteudo_2{
  display:none
}
.conteudo_3{
  display:none
}

.active{
  display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(1)">Conteudo 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(2)">Conteudo 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(3)">Conteudo 3</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_1">
<p>
texto conteudo 1
</p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_2">
<p>
texto conteudo 2
</p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_3">
<p>
texto conteudo 3
</p>
</div>
```

Apenas criei uma função que esconde todas as divs com a classe `.conteudo` e exibo a que foi clicada.

Answer (score 1):

Acho q dá pra simplificar o código, e ainda reaproveitar facilmente

```js
function toggleDiv(conteudo){
  $('.conteudo').hide();
  if(conteudo == 1) {
    $('.conteudo_1').show();
  } else if(conteudo == 2) {
    $('.conteudo_2').show();
  } else if(conteudo == 3) {
    $('.conteudo_3').show();
  } 
}
```

```css
.conteudo{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(1)">Conteudo 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(2)">Conteudo 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv(3)">Conteudo 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_1">
<p>texto conteudo 1</p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_2">
<p>texto conteudo 2</p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo conteudo_3">
<p>texto conteudo 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa, melhorou memso :D